# silverlight selectively bind properties to piechart?

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, charts, pie-chart

If I have a custom class that contains a number of properties, how do I bind a selected few of them to a silverlight toolkit pie chart? For example:

```
public class Expense
{
    public double food;
    public string food_description;
    public double rent;
    public string rent_description;
    public double renterInsurance;
    public string renterInsurance_description;

    ...
}
```

How do I bind this to a pie chart so "food" and "renterInsurance" are visualized in the pie chart (but not "rent"), with their corresponding description shown in the legend?

This stemmed from an unanswered question I posted a bit earlier. Someone made a suggestion that I think might be helpful if the data structure is tweaked. But it depends on if this question will be answered.

Here is my original question. If you have a good answer I'd really appreciate it:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704622/silverlight-can-i-do-this-through-data-binding

Answer (score 0):

Do like this,

```
 PieSeries pie1 = new PieSeries();
 pie1.IndependentValueBinding = new Binding("food");
                                pie1.DependentValueBinding=new Binding("renterInsurance");
                                pie1.ItemsSource = tempData;
                                chart1.Series.Add(pie1);

 pie1.ItemsSource = List<YourClass>;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sajeetharan. However, "food" and "renterInsurance" both need to be bound as DependentValue, as those are the two values that make up the pie. I'd also need to bind both "_description" to the same pie series, so the descriptions show up in the legend.